# Installing a Visual Studio Extension

Tags: visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-extensions

I've just started using VS2015 and I'm having trouble doing something that should be simple... install the Side Waffle extension.

From their website I downloaded the .vsix file, templatepack.vsix. When I double click on it, I get an message, "The extension manifest is invalid."

So I went into Visual Studio 2015, went to Tools > Extensions and Updates, and found it under 'Online'.  But the only option is to download it.  There is no "Install" option.

I went back to the download folder, and on templatepack.vsix I did a right-click and open-with, then tried Microsoft Visual Studio Version Selector. Again I got the message "The extension manifest is invalid."

I tried just dragging the .vsix file into Visual Studio, but that just opened the file so I could edit it. It didn't install it.

I'm out of ideas.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, figured it out.  Located here:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE
```

There is an app called: VSIXInstaller.exe

Right-clicked on the extension > Open-With > Choose Default Program > More Options > Scroll down to 'Look for another app on this PC' > navigate to the location of VSIXInstaller.exe and select it.

That did the trick.

Comment: That should have been set up for you. Any idea if something happened that might have broken the association?

Comment: No idea.  Not sure how I would even find out.

Comment: Eh, I was hoping you would know. :-) If you knew something weird happened then we might have a useful repro to investigate, otherwise we'll just call it one of life's mysteries.

Answer (score 2):

I tried @Casey Crookston answer but it is not working on Visual Studio Enterprise 2017 (version 15.3.5)

This is my solution:

1. Open Visual Studio.
2. Go to Tool > Extensions and Updates > Choose Online > Search the
   file you want to install > Click Download.
   [image: Screenshot of Extensions and Updates]
3. Close all Visual Studio instances.
4. The installation should start immediately.