# Installing Visual Studio Installer Projects extension offline

Tags: visual-studio

The Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Projects web pag at VisualStudio Marketplace has a Download button for offline installation, but the resulting file is a compressed file InstallerProjects.zip which contains lots of different folders and files but no installation instructions. How do I install this extension?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though the file is called InstallerProjects.zip, it is actually a .vsix file and can be installed as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33501169/installing-a-visual-studio-extension):

There is an app called: VSIXInstaller.exe. Its exact location depends on which version of Visual Studio you are using; for me it is located at

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE
```

Right-clicked on the extension file > Open-With > Choose Default Program > More Options > Scroll down to 'Look for another app on this PC' > navigate to the location of VSIXInstaller.exe and select it.